# Resolve conflicts between two protected branches by creating PR

Tags: git, github

I am having two branches `master` and `develop` both are protected i.e we can't push on them without creating PR. Now the scenario is when I create a PR for `master` branch from `develop` there is conflicts appear.

I tried creating new branch from `develop` branch called `resolve_conflicts` and take pull from master `git pull origin master` then resolved conflicts and pushed `resolve_conflicts` branch and then create PR for `develop`.
after merging `resolve_conflicts` branch to `develop` branch I thought my initial conflict should resolved i.e for `master` and `develop` but it is still displaying conflicts.

Is there any way I can resolve this conflicts by creating PR, I can't directly push on develop branch as it is protected from direct push.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, what you've described should work, but without knowing the exact state of your repo, I can't say for sure what's happening.

Perhaps somebody else has introduced additional changes into either `master` or `develop`?

Or maybe HEAD wasn't where you thought it was when you were doing those operations?

Try using `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` to inspect the commit tree. If the branch you want to merge is a direct descendent of the base commit, you're guaranteed to have no merge conflicts.

Comment: "based off `master`" means I need to create resolve_conflicts from `master` branch?

Comment: Yes, `master` needs to be an ancestor of `resolve_conflicts`. In fact, since you already resolved the conflicts in the other direction, there is a way to reuse it as to not need to resolve them again. However, it's complicated to explain without knowing the exact state of the repo.

Comment: What if `master` is behind `develop`, and both branches are protected?

Comment: If by "behind" you mean a direct ancestor of, then there won't be any conflicts when merging.